# Indentation different level of appendix entries in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, appendices

I'm writing my thesis paper, I got a tough question. How do I change the indent of A.l Coverable Region 1 inch after the Appendix A, so on and so forth for A.1.1 and A.1.2 [image]

```
\newcommand\appendix{%dottedtocline
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
  \newpage
  %\par\null\vfill
%   \vspace*{-0.45in}
  \vspace*{0.64in}
  \def\@appname{\appendicesname}
  \textbf{\hfill\@appname\hfill}
  \par\vfill\par
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\uppercase{\@appname}}}
  \let\chapter=\appendixchapter
  \addtolength{\textheight}{-\appendixheadheight}
  \addtolength{\textheight}{-\appendixheadsep}}

\newcommand{\appendixchapter}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \doublespacing
  \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{%
    \protect\numberline{%
      \appendixchaptername\space\thechapter}%
      %\hspace*{-0.25in}
    \ignorespaces{#1}}
  \@makeappendixhead{#1}}
```

Comment: please add a `MWE`, i.e. starting with `documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so that people can copy paste your code and try it out.